# Wordpress - add woocommerce billing_phone field into user-new.php and save it into database and my account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm facing a problem. I need to create some woocommerce customer role accounts manualy from the wp-admin. What I need to do is to add a woocommerce billing_phone number into the form which will be saved into the database and added to woocommerce my account phone field automatically. I've tried to do it with the code bellow but it did not help. Any ideas how could I make it?

I need to add it to user-new.php ...I know there is possibility to add the billing_phone after I create the user account, but I want to save time by searching for the account and doing things twice so I want to save time by adding this field directly into the account creation process from wp-admin.

Thank you in advance!

Code I used but did not help:

```
add_action( 'user_new_form', function( $type ){
    if( 'add-new-user' !== $type )
        return;
    echo '<input type="text" name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" value=""/>';
});
```

[image]

Comment: When do you want this to happen? Or are you trying to create a function which you would run as per your requirement and that would sync all the phone numbers with bliing_phone_number ? This isn't clear from your question.

Also there is no default phone number field in woocommerce. Have you created a custom user field for it ? If yes what's the `meta_key` of it ?

Comment: No, I use woocommerce on my website. We use a woocommerce bookings plugin to sell our therapies to customers. If customer orders with email or he calls to our saloon we create his account manualy and then we assign his account into the order we create. So we need to add a field where we will add customers phone and this phone number will appear in woocommerce billing details as phone number.

Comment: I need this to happen when you create account in wordpress admin - > as I mentioned in my question its page called user-new.php

Comment: Wp-admin -> users -> add new user (here it will happen)

Comment: So, you just want a field where you can mobile_number of customer and when you are creating an order for him/her you want that phone number to autmatically get inserted into billing_mobile_field same as it happens with email ID ? Correct ?

Comment: Yes thats it. With email it works great and I need to do the same with phone number. @Bhanu

Comment: @Bhanu do you know any solution how to figure it out please? :) I will appreciate your help if you do

Comment: I have just posted an answer. Check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very easy to do. So the way WooCommerce autofills those fields is if by fetching the actually billing and shipping addresses for the user. If we manage so save the users contact number on regster hook we can make this work.

We will first create a field to save mobile data.

```php
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'bks_add_mobile_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'bks_add_mobile_field' );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'bks_add_mobile_field' );

function bks_add_mobile_field( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="mobile"><?php _e("Mobile Number"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mobile', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter mobile."); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```

Now we would save this mobile in both the fields `mobile` and `billing_mobile`.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'bks_save_mobile_field' );

function bks_save_mobile_field($user_id) {
    // You can maybe add checks here whch would determine if the users role is customer 
    // or not or maybe validate the number. 
    if ( isset( $_POST['mobile'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'mobile', $_POST['mobile']);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', $_POST['mobile']);
    }
}
```

So to put it all together add the following code in your `functions.php` file.

```php
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'bks_add_mobile_field' );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'bks_add_mobile_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'bks_add_mobile_field' );

function bks_add_mobile_field( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="mobile"><?php _e("Mobile Number"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mobile', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter mobile."); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }


add_action( 'user_register', 'bks_save_mobile_field' );

function bks_save_mobile_field($user_id) {
    // You can maybe add checks here whch would determine if the users role is customer 
    // or not or maybe validate the number. 
    if ( isset( $_POST['mobile'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'mobile', $_POST['mobile']);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', $_POST['mobile']);
    }
}
```

This code is tested and it WORKS.

[image: Order Screenshot]

Comment: Is there a way to edit this code and include all default woocommerce billing fields into the user-new.php page? Reason being, billing country and billing state are dynamic fields in woocommerce.

Comment: @MubasharAftab, I think you can do it, but it will be a lot of duplicate fields that you will have to create. And update the other "WooCommerce" field using the duplicate fields.